# why is my printer printing black on white labels?

Tags: printing, network-printer, hp-laserjet, label

I have a hp laser jet P2050 printer, i am trying to print a simple text on a sticker, i attach the sticker which is white and the white paper and try to print it out, the print comes on the sticker but its all blacked out, the paper however is white, when i try to print it on only paper its printed fine, i tried to print a white sheet too to try and see if the sticker comes black, and yes its black, what could be the cause? i am out of options atm.

Comment: Is it possible to make a photo of it and share it? Otherwise its guessing work. My initial thought is that the sticker itself might be thermal based and just heating it up causes black to appear. If this is the case just the movement of the printer causes it all to become black. Do note that thermal based stickers are not suitable for a normal printer, and cannot be used.

Comment: well, i guess so thats the case, because just as of now , i used alchol swab over the sticker and all the black part is gone and sticker became clear , this means there is extra ink of printer thats comming on the sticker, well this seems to be a trick to avoid it, like just use a cotton bud dipped in alchol swab or thinner and move it over it and all that black shade is gone..

Answer (score 0):

From your comment (you can wipe the toner off the label with alcohol), it looks as if the labels are not laser-compatible. What kind of labels are these? If they are inkjet labels, DO NOT use them as they can damage a laser printer.

If they are laser-compatible, another possibility is that you have not told the printer that you are printing labels. This is normally done in the driver or, in the case of Word, from Page Setup. Set the paper type to "Label". You can also try selecting "Cardstock" or "Transparencies", in case they are not normal labels.

The reason for selecting different paper types is that the printer needs to apply different heat settings to fuse the toner onto the paper. Heavy papers require more heat to do the job. That is also why most printers run slower for card than for plain paper: the slow speed gives the card more time to heat up.

Answer (score 0):

if your printer doesn't support labels but you can buy a printer that support labels or select card as paper type. if it printing is bad it's most likly the sticky bit. we Bought a [**brother**](https://global.brother/en?utm_source=brother.com_via_CGI&utm_medium=referral&utm_expid=.DDbM2-wVRlWSgNM0d9RQNg.0&utm_referrer=) [***mfc-l2710dw***](https://www.brother.co.uk/printers/mono-laser-printers/mfc-l2710dw) and it worked just fine, we don't use it often
based on online user guide, all black.
Clean the corona wire inside the drum unit.
The drum unit may be damaged,[all black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz31O.gif)
Replace the drum unit with a new drum unit.
TIP: don't put label on paper because you're confusing the printer, print the whole sheet of the label.

```
   https://global.brother/en/gateway (global(select country, select printers, click  meno laser printers, click all in one laser printers and click mfc-l2710dw)
```